# Why this transplant function works for a binary search tree?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

In the chapter on binary search tree's in CLRS and I encountered the transplant function which replaces a node `u` with node `v` with appropriate changes in the parent element.
Here is the code I wrote for transplant function:

```
void transplant(Node* root, Node* u, Node* v)
{
    if(u->parent == NULL)
        root = v;
    else if(u == u->parent->left)
        u->parent->left = v;
    else
        u->parent->right = v;
    if(v != NULL)
        v->parent = u->parent;
}
```

It's not that I don't understand how this works but that why this works. When I make a function call I'm basically sending a copy of pointers `root`, `u`, `v` to the function right ? so the changes made in the function shouldn't actually reflect on the root unless I return it or use pointer to pointer type but its actually changing the original root. I defined root as global variable, does that change anything ?

Comment: How you call the function? And how is the `root` created?

Comment: It shouldn't work if `u` is `root`, then you actually only change the local copy of `root`. In the other cases, you have pointers pointing to the actual `Node`s and change those.

Comment: i called the function as `transplant(root, z, z->right)` `root` is a pointer to a struct defined globally as `Node* root = NULL`

Comment: @Aryan Try calling it with `transplant(root, root, root->right)` and see whether `root` changes in `main`.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes it did change `root` to `NULL`

Comment: @Aryan Is `root->parent == NULL` in `main`? If not, that explains it, if it is, then your compiler must be totally broken.

Comment: @DanielFischer yes `root->parent = NULL`, i took care of that in the insert procedure. the `root` is defined globally so does that mean a global can be changed in any function even though functions get a copy of vars ?

Comment: Check it explicitly when calling. The parameter name `root` in the function definition shadows the global name `root`, so that is _not_ accessible from the function without some contortions (new local scope with an `extern` declaration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function will not work if `u->parent` is `NULL`, in that case, only the local variable `root` is set to `v`, nothing accessible from outside the function changes.

If `u->parent != NULL`, then `u->parent->left` and `u->parent->right` are the members of the `Node` pointed to by `u->parent`, and those are overwritten, so the changes are visible in `main`.